# Configure behat with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, testing, behat

I'm trying to configure Behat, but I have some errors. Here is config:

```
default:
suites:
  default:
      contexts:
          - FeatureContext:
              session:   '@session'
extensions:
  Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
  Behat\MinkExtension:
      sessions:
      default:
      symfony2: ~
```

Import to config.yml. And when I try run clear:cache or bin/behat I getting:

```
 There is no extension able to load the configuration for "default" (in /var/www/ontheway/app/config/behat.yml). Looked for namespace "default", found "framework", "security", "twig",
```

I do all steps what described here:
[behat docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/cookbooks/1.symfony2_integration.html)
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the exact YML you've created? If so, then it's indented incorrectly on the second line. There you should have another indentation level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sharing what I have been using for all my Symfony2 projects. Behat+Mink+Selenium

**COMPOSER:**

**mySymfonyProject/composer.json:**

```
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "2.5.*@stable",
    "behat/behat-bundle": "1.0.0",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "1.1.2",
    "behat/mink": "1.5.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "~1.3",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.1.1",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.0.9"
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

**BEHAT**

**mySymfonyProject/behat.yml:**

```
default:
    context:
        class: FeatureContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://mysymfonyproject.local/app_test.php/'
            javascript_session: selenium2
            browser_name: firefox
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
    paths:
        features: %behat.paths.base%/src
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context
```

**SELENIUM**

Download into your project. It is [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), **make sure** you download 2.43.1 version which is in the middle of the page.

Run it: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar`

**CONTEXT FEATURE**

**mySymfonyProject/src/Site/CommonBundle/Features/Context/FeatureContext.php**

```
<?php

namespace Site\CommonBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * Hold Symfony kernel object.
     *
     * @var object Kernel Object.
     */
    protected $kernel;

    /**
     * Helps to use doctrine and entity manager.
     *
     * @param KernelInterface $kernelInterface Interface for getting Kernel.
     */
    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernelInterface)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;
    }

    //And your own methods
}
```

**TESTS**

When you have feature files you can run them like this (this runs all in one go. for more info read behat doc):

```
bin/behat @SiteCommonBundle
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import `behat.yml` in your `config.yml`.

Behat works independently from Symfony. And these configs cannot be messed. In the documentation from link that you provide you can find that `behat.yml` must be located at the project's root folder.

Comment: Whoops. That looks a lot like the correct answer. I didn't notice @Panzer_Commander was importing the YML.

Comment: ok, I am exclude importing of behat,eml to config. But now when I am run bin/behat I am get this error``FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.`

Comment: Did you place your `FeatureContext.php` in `PROJECT_ROOT/features/Context`?

Comment: Also if you really have wrong indentations (your indentations not the same as in documentation) it can be parsed wrong way. If you have right indentation fix it in your question.